# How to create Apple Watch target in Xcode 6.2 beta 4

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I want to create `iWatch` app in my project. How to create iWatch traget by using xcode 6.2 beta 4

Any idea about `iWatchkit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an iWatch target follow these steps:

1. Create a new project for iOS and after that, add a new target

[image: first screenshot]

2. Select `WatchKit App` and click `Next`

[image: second screenshot]

3. It automatically created `WatchKit`. Now we can select it's storyboard file. When building the project for `iWatch`, you need to select that target.

[image: third screenshot]